# Problems reading data from a microSD card

Tags: microcontroller, pic, spi, sd

I am trying to read a block of data from a standard capacity micro SD card, but the received data does not make any sense. Here is what I'm doing:

- Initializing the card
- Reading data

  - Setting CS low
  - Sending CMD16 to set block length
  - Sending CMD17 with start address
  - Waiting for start byte (0xfe)
  - Receiving bytes and printing them to the serial terminal
  - Receiving CRC
  - Setting CS high
  - Sending 8 extra clocks (?)

The data I'm trying to read is the FAT16 boot sector, as shown below:
[image: Card contents]
And the data I'm getting out is this:
[image]

At this point, I can't even begin to think of what is going wrong. I don't think it's a transmission error, because the data out is always the same. I can also read the boot sector signature 0x55 0xAA every time, even if I set the start address to 510 and read two bytes, they come back perfectly. The problem is that I can't read other bytes.

I also tried swapping cards and that didn't help either.

What am I missing?

EDIT: the function in question is below.

```c
bit sd_read_block(unsigned long size, unsigned long start_addr)
{
    unsigned long i;
    unsigned char r;

    SD_CS = 0;

    r = sd_card_cmd(16, size, 0);

    sprintf(usb_uart_tx_buffer, "CMD16 R Token: %02x.\r\n", r);
    usb_uart_tx(usb_uart_tx_buffer);

    r = sd_card_cmd(17, start_addr, 0);

    sprintf(usb_uart_tx_buffer, "CMD17 R Token: %02x.\r\n", r);
    usb_uart_tx(usb_uart_tx_buffer);

    // wait for start token
    r = 0;
    while (spi_rx_byte() != 0xfe) {
        if (r++ > 25) {
            SD_CS = 1;
            return r;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (i % 20 == 0) {
            UART1_TX(0x0d);
            UART1_TX(0x0a);
        }
        sprintf(usb_uart_tx_buffer, "%02x ", spi_rx_byte());
        usb_uart_tx(usb_uart_tx_buffer);
    }

    // CRC
    spi_rx_byte();
    spi_rx_byte();

    // extra clocks
    r = spi_rx_byte();

    SD_CS = 1;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I cannot really say what is going on- but there seems to be maybe byte size is incorrect - as fat16 uses different size than fat32/ntfs..  All the 00 at the start do not make sense. and then it seems some bytes are missing/ compressed? there is something wrong with the way the bytes are recived/ interpreted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It turns out that I was reading the MBR, which is located at the address `0` on the SD card. To find the location of the boot sector, one needs to read the appropriate entry in the MBR. The entries start at the address `0x01be` and are 16 bytes each.  The point of interest in the entry lies at the offset `0x08`, is 4 bytes long and is called an LBA. [[Wikipedia]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) To get the address of the boot sector location, one would multiply the LBA by the size of a sector (512 bytes). [[Microchip forum]](http://www.microchip.com/forums/fb.ashx?m=129038)

For example:

In the output above, the four entries look like this:

```
00 02 10 00 06 2f ef af 8d 00 00 00 73 0f 3a 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

As you can see, only one entry is used. The LBA in this case is `8d 00 00 00` and is in little-endian format, so in big-endian it would be `0x8d` or 141 in decimal. Multiply this by 512 and you get 72192 (`0x11a00`). This is the address of the sector where the FAT starts.